# Cart price issue for some products

Tags: cart, price, special-price, magento1.9.2.4

We have a magento multistore website and we are facing an issue with the pricing in Cart. Products on magento are pushed from ERP system. The products pricing is website specific.

I will explain the complete scenario here:

We have near about 8k products in our store. And near about 50 products are showing different price from their final price in Cart Page. There is no difference between the products which are showing wrong price and the products which are showing correct price.

And the products which are showing wrong price are actually showing Original price in place of Special Price. I have debugged alot on it and I found the following points on it:

1. When I open a product in magento admin and save it on default view, its price gets correct and it show correct price in cart page also. But if I save by selecting correct store view, it does not affect anything.
2. When we click on add to cart button, Quote **_initItem()** method is
   called twice. **_initItem()** save the item quote price on **sales_flat_quote_item** table. On first call the **$finalprice** is the correct and on second time it saves wrong price.
3. I have checked the price on different observers like: **checkout_cart_product_add_after** & **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** and here the price is correct.

If anyone faced this kind of issue, Please let me know. Or if someone have any doubt or wants to help please let me konw.